# IndexError: index 1431 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 741

Tags: python, image, index-error

I am defining a region growing function with a tolerance. I am limiting x and y within image dimensions.
While I work with either x or y, the code works.
But when I use both x and y, code generates an error:

```
"IndexError: index 1431 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 741"
```

Also, the output image (when using either x or y), generates an image with interchanged axes (773 x 741). Image dimensions are 741 x 773.

Image:

```
    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wpUAAdU8DeJjp0TLY19X1FJ-xW2-JEma/view?usp=sharing
```

Can you suggest where I am making a mistake?

code for Function: region_growing_average

```
def distance(a, b):
    return np.abs(int(a)-int(b))                       

#for a two-dimentional image and a single marker [x,y] position
def region_growing_average(img, img_t, tolerance, marker, m=0):
    
    # include this statement before applying region growing: img_t = np.zeros(img.shape)
    x = marker[0]
    y = marker[1]
    if (x+1 < img.shape[0] and x-1 >=0 and y+1 < img.shape[1] and y-1 >=0):
        img_t[x, y] = 1
        
        # check matrix border and conquering criterion for the 4-neigbourhood
        if (x+1 < img_t.shape[0] and img_t[x+1,y] == 0  and distance(img[x-m,y], img[x+1, y]) <= tolerance):
            region_growing_average(img, img_t, tolerance, [x+1, y], m+1)
            
        if (x-1 >= 0 and img_t[x-1,y] == 0  and distance(img[x+m,y], img[x-1, y]) <= tolerance):
            print(x,y, m, x+m, img[x+m,y], img[x, y+1], distance(img[x+m,y], img[x-1, y]))
            region_growing_average(img, img_t, tolerance, [x-1, y], m+1)
            
        if (y+1 < img_t.shape[1] and img_t[x,y+1] == 0 and distance(img[x,y-m], img[x, y+1]) <= tolerance):
            region_growing_average(img, img_t, tolerance, [x, y+1], m+1)
            
        if (y-1 >= 0 and img_t[x,y-1] == 0  and distance(img[x,y+m], img[x, y+1]) <= tolerance):
            region_growing_average(img, img_t, tolerance, [x, y-1], m+1)
        
    #It will return a binary image: img_t
```

```
img = im[:,:,2]  ##trying only one band
img_t = np.zeros(img.shape)
marker = [50,250]
region_growing_average(img, img_t, 257, marker)  #it should generate a white image
```

Comment: Can you post the full code, including where you read the image?

Comment: Here is code for image reading: `im = imread('E2_ractangular_halfway.tif')[:,:,0:3]` and image print: `print("image size:",im.shape)`